# angular-datatable auto trigger responsive behavior

Tags: angularjs, datatables

Is there a way to auto trigger the responsive behavior of angular datatable?

I found a way to manually trigger this by using with `.withOption('responsive', true);`. But cant get it to auto trigger when user re-sizes the screen.

following is the code i'm using to manually trigger responsiveness.

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function () {
            return rWarehouse.query().$promise;
        }).withOption('responsive', false);
```

here are the columns

```
 $scope.dtColumns = [ 
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('organisation.name').withTitle('Organisation'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Warehouse').withClass('none'),
          DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('code').withTitle('Warehouse Code').withClass('none'),              
        ];
```

BTW i'm using this http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome angular datatable.

Comment: Did you make sure to have included the supporting CSS and JS files. [According](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/42) to the author of `angular-datatables`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have set the responsive property false in your code.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function () {
        return rWarehouse.query().$promise;
    }).withOption('responsive', true);
```

It should work just fine.

Another way you can do this is by using bootstraps table-responsive class in your HTML.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions"></table>
</div>
```

It'll add a horizontal scroll bar to your table. But the first solution is much better.

You can also check for more info at this [Github Issue](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/42)